# Docker-compose failed to restart inside ubuntu image

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Im trying to host web app inside docker container and for it i need docker-compose in docker. I installed docker-compose inside ubuntu image and that solution worked! (im running container with privileged mode)

Image file:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -qy full-upgrade && \
    apt-get -qy install sudo && \
    apt-get install -qy curl && \
    apt-get install -qy nginx && \
    apt-get install -qy ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release && \
    mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg && \
    echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -qy docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io && \
    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.6/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

WORKDIR /home

COPY ****secret****
COPY ****secret****
COPY ****secret****

COPY docker /home/docker
COPY ****secret****
COPY ****secret****
COPY ****secret****

EXPOSE 3000 7777
COPY dockerized_build/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo service docker start
sudo nginx -g daemon off;
sudo service nginx restart
cd /home/docker && sudo docker-compose up
```

All working fine after container creation, but if i want to restart container with **docker restart** or **sudo docker restart** it throws this error(its full container log):

```
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/devices: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/net_prio: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/pids: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma: permission denied.
mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/misc: permission denied.
 * Starting Docker: docker                                                                                                                                                                              [ OK ]
nginx: invalid option: "off"
 * Restarting nginx nginx                                                                                                                                                                               [ OK ]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
  File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
  File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
  File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
  File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
  File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
  File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
  File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
  File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  File "compose/cli/main.py", line 198, in perform_command
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
  File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
  File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
  File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))
[128] Failed to execute script docker-compose
```

Any suggestions? I really got stuck on that problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Its working finally!! For everyone else solution was to shutdown docker inside docker before container shutdown.

Entrypoint:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo service docker start
sudo service nginx restart
cd /home/docker && sudo docker-compose up -d

onContainerStop() {
    echo "Container stopped, performing docker restart procedure..."
    # shellcheck disable=SC2046
    sudo docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
    sudo service docker stop
    sudo service nginx stop
}

trap 'onContainerStop' SIGTERM

while true; do :; done
```